# Validating that cell values are correspondent to other cell values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, cell

I am currently working on a project that requires data cleansing. I am trying to validate that a value in a cell in another column corresponds to another value on the same row but on another column. For example

```
      Type      Type_ID

      Apple     12
      Banana    13
      Mango     14
      Fig       15
      Orange    16
```

I want to write a script that validates that all rows that have the type as "apple" will have the type_ID "12" which is an identifier I use for apples. How can I do that? I want it to display something like an error for example when a row has "orange" as a type and "12" as type_ID. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an idea. You can group by `Type_ID` and check whether there is only one `Type` for each `Type_ID`.
Here I just set up an easy understandable solution.

```
require(dplyr)

check_doubles <- function(df){

  df <- df %>% 
    group_by(Type_ID) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(Type) > 1)

  if(nrow(df) > 1) print(df)

}
```

You can go with something fancier by using this. It actually prints an error only if there is an issue and uses Non Standard Evaluation syntax to make it a reusable function that can be used with columns with different names.

```
require(dplyr)

check_doubles <- function(.data, .id, .check){

  .id <- enquo(.id)
  .check <- enquo(.check)

  .data <- .data %>% 
    group_by(!!.id) %>% 
    filter(n_distinct(!!.check) > 1)

  if(nrow(.data) > 1){ 

    print(.data)
    stop("More than one value for each .id!\n", call. = FALSE)

  }

}

df <- tibble(Type  = c("Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Fig", "Orange"),
             Type_ID = c(12, 13, 14, 15, 16))

check_doubles(df, Type_ID, Type)

#>

df <- tibble(Type  = c("Apple", "Banana", "Mango", "Fig", "Orange"),
             Type_ID = c(12, 12, 14, 15, 16))

check_doubles(df, Type_ID, Type)

#>  # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>  # Groups:   Type_ID [1]
#>    Type   Type_ID
#>    <chr>    <dbl>
#>  1 Apple       12
#>  2 Banana      12
#>  Error: More than one value for each .id!
```